# after clicking on toggle how to change button value is click value on toggle list in angularJs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

After clicking on toggle how to change button value is click value on toggle list in angularJs ?

I have write this code please help me ? I have also explain the code how it work i need only after clicking on toggle how to change button value is click value on toggle list in angularJs .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #3498DB;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
     min-width: 162px;
     position:reletive;
font-weight:bold;
}

.dropbtn:after{
    content: '';
    border-top: 8px solid white;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    left: 75px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 37px;

}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;

}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border:1px solid  #3498DB;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;

}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
     border-top:2px solid  #3498DB;
}



.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
</style>
</head>
```

**Write a html code**

```
<body>

<h2>Clickable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="test" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
   window.onclick = function(event) {
   if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have got the selected value within the javascript, assign that to the button value, using the following code:

```
document.getElementById("button_Name").innerHTML = selectedValueFromDropdown;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your window.onclick function, you can add this fix :

```
if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn a')) {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = event.target.innerHTML;
}
```

So that if you click on one of your "options" button, the innerHTML (the text) of your dropdown button takes the one of the option.

Full code (or [CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/marcoom74/pen/oMdKNO) :

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
   window.onclick = function(event) {
   if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
     if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn a')) {
       document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = event.target.innerHTML;
     }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #3498DB;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
     min-width: 162px;
     position:reletive;
font-weight:bold;
}

.dropbtn:after{
    content: '';
    border-top: 8px solid white;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    left: 75px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 37px;

}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;

}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border:1px solid  #3498DB;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;

}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
     border-top:2px solid  #3498DB;
}



.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
```

```html
<body>

<h2>Clickable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="test" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

And by the way, in your code, you don't use AngularJS :)